# Unmet Dependencies Issue -- Gnome Terminal

Tags: apt, dependencies, gnome-terminal

I have been running into the following issue when trying to `apt-get` almost anything and cannot seem to find a solution.

Example 1:

```
~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-terminal : Depends: gnome-terminal-data (>= 3.18) but 3.6.2-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Example 2:

```
~$ sudo apt-get -f upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-terminal : Depends: gnome-terminal-data (>= 3.18) but 3.6.2-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Example 3:

```
~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-terminal : Depends: gnome-terminal-data (>= 3.18) but 3.6.2-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

How do I resolve this issue? What exactly is my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to enter the following into terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal-data
```

This fixed all my issues.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you mix up sources or sources are outdated. First run `apt-get update` and watch out for any error messages. Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` if everything is as it should be. Check any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` if one looks like the cause of an update error.

If update runs through without errors 'apt-get -f install' should be able to fix the problem.

If it persists, turn off sources one by one and rerun update/install until you identified the troublemaker.

When you check your sources look for wrong distributions. I run trusty and also have gnome-terminal 3.6.2-0ubuntu1. Maybe you have a source that points to a newer distribution?